# Rotating an SVG element 360 degrees does nothing

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transform, css-transforms

I'm using d3.js. I'm trying to rotate an SVG element 360 degrees, so that it spins once and returns to it's original position.

Rotating it 3/4 of the way like this works fine:

```
    thing
        .transition()
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(270,640,426)')
        .duration(6000);
```

But trying to animate the complete rotation does nothing:

```
    thing
        .transition()
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(360,640,426)')
        .duration(6000);
```

I think d3 (or maybe this a more general fact about svg transform attribute) sees that the end is the same as the beginning and just takes the shortcut by doing nothing. Similarly, if I do 365 degrees, it only moves +5 degrees.

A. Why is this?
B. What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

D3 normalizes the SVG transforms; this is the cause for the effect you're seeing. You can do this however with a custom tween function:

```
function rotTween() {
  var i = d3.interpolate(0, 360);
  return function(t) {
    return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
  };
}
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FZXwH/).